# Android: GoogleMap callbacks not being called

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I've started a new Android project based around a Google map using the Android Studio template, and my callbacks are not getting called at all.

Here is my activity code:

```
class MapsActivity : BaseActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    }

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap

        val center = LatLng(/*Redacted*/)

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(center, 18.0F))

        mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener { GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener {
            val bounds = mMap.projection.visibleRegion.latLngBounds
        } }

        mMap.setOnMapClickListener { GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener {
            val lat = it.latitude
        } }

        mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener { GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener {
            val bounds = mMap.projection.visibleRegion.latLngBounds
        } }

        mMap.setOnCameraMoveListener { GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener {
            val bounds = mMap.projection.visibleRegion.latLngBounds
        } }
    }
}
```

The contents of the callbacks aren't important at the moment, I'm setting breakpoints within them all and none of them are getting called.

Here's my app gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "redacted"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
}
```

This might be a red herring, but occasionally I get an error in the console and the map stops working at all:

```
A/art: art/runtime/stack.cc:153] Check failed: success Failed to read the this object in void com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.drawable.y.a(com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.f, com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.camera.c, com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.m)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

Here's my manifest file as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="redacted">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>

        <activity
                android:name=".MapsActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Edit 2:

Here's my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          tools:context=".MapsActivity"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Comment: How does your AndroidManifest file look like? Have you added the required permissions?

Comment: @Eenvincible I've added it to my post, but it's unchanged from what Android Studio generated.

Comment: I still do not see the INTERNET permission; also remember to initialize the API client as noted in the answer by @banu Prakash

Comment: @Eenvincible I've since added the internet permission and initialised the API client, neither made any difference

Comment: @IanNewson Can you post your layout file activity_maps?

Comment: "minSdkVersion 23" This made me think, do you request the permission at runtime? Because writing that in the manifest is not enough. Also adding `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` might help.

Comment: @FurkanYurdakul I don't but I would expect that to be handled by the maps SDK. The map itself displays fine but callbacks aren't called. Weirdly I rewrote it into Java and it works fine.

Comment: Huh. Weird indeed. Then the only thing I can come up with is that I guess the listeners' syntax is wrong? Because on interface declarations they mostly start with either `object: ` or just attached directly with a bracket. Your code does a different approach, it uses two brackets and defines the call without the `object: ` in front of it. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: @IanNewson When you say break points in "callbacks" are not getting called, you mean only mapready callback or any other as well?

Comment: @Zaartha onMapReady is called, but setOnCameraChangeListener, setOnMapClickListener, setOnCameraIdleListener and setOnCameraMoveListener are not.

Comment: @IanNewson Check my answer. I faced the same problem as you did. Now its working with my implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: This breakpoint in your code will hit]
In your code the above breakpoint will hit.

Try this. In order for the function to execute you need to go by one of the following approaches.

```
class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener, GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener {

private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
}



override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap

    val center = LatLng(/*Redacted*/)
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(center, 18.0F))

    mMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(this)
    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this)

}

override fun onCameraMove() {
    val i = 0
    val bounds = mMap.projection.visibleRegion.latLngBounds

}

override fun onMapClick(p0: LatLng?) {
    val i = 0
    val bounds = mMap.projection.visibleRegion.latLngBounds
}

}
```

Or another way to set listeners is as follows

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap

    val center = LatLng(/*Redacted*/)

    mMap.setOnCameraMoveListener {
        val bounds = mMap.projection.visibleRegion.latLngBounds
    }

    mMap.setOnMapClickListener  {
        val bounds = mMap.projection.visibleRegion.latLngBounds

    }

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(center, 18.0F))

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This is helpful but I'd really like to understand why the original code doesn't work to further my understanding of kotlin.

Comment: @IanNewson I have updated my answer. The original code didn't work because your listener is {GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener {val bounds = mMap.projection.visibleRegion.latLngBounds}} rather than just {val bounds = mMap.projection.visibleRegion.latLngBounds}. If you put a breakpoint on "GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener" it will hit.

Comment: I'm even more confused now, because I used the build in Android Studio feature to convert my Java class that worked to Kotlin, and it generated `mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener {` and it works! I don't understand, but I'm going to leave this behind me now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you have to initialize google api client in onCreate() method.

```
mGoogleApiClient = GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
        .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
        .enableAutoManage(this, this)
        .build()
```

Comment: That made no difference unfortunately.

Comment: you have to add this lines before getMapAsync(this)

Comment: Still made no difference unfortunately